# Как в java сделать скриншот окна

Tags: java, swing, экран

Есть код:

```
public static BufferedImage getScreenComponent(Component c)
{   
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try
    {
        image = new Robot().createScreenCapture
        (
            new Rectangle
            (
                c.getLocationOnScreen().x,
                c.getLocationOnScreen().y,
                c.getWidth(),
                c.getHeight()
            )
        );
    } catch(Exception e) {}  
    return image;
}
```

По сути эта функция должна снимать скриншот компонента. Но у нее есть один минус:
При перегораживании компонента, например окном получается скрин этого компонента, перегороженный окном. Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно просто сказать окну «нарисуй себя», передав ему `Graphics`, созданный этим самым `BufferedImage`:

```
public static BufferedImage getScreenComponent(Component component) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
      component.getWidth(),
      component.getHeight(),
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
      );
    component.paint( image.getGraphics() );
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывести компонент на экран поверх всего.
Это скриншот - он отображает то, что в данный момент на экране, а не то, что может быть там где-то на несколько уровней ниже.

Либо реализовывать функцию не через скриншот, а получать изображение компонента из самого компонента (сложно сказать как, ведь непонятно что это за компонент)

Comment: Компонент = JPanel :)